# How do I add a delay to the .slideUp function in Balsamiq Mockups?

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

```
<js> $("#curtain").slideUp("slow"); $("#curtain").slideDown("slow"); </js>
```

Now what do I do, if I want to add a delay of 100ms between the .slideUp and slideDown?

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery 1.4, it's as easy as

```
$("#curtain").slideUp("slow").delay(500).slideDown("slow");
```

On older version you had to use the animation callback and setTimeout:

```
$("#curtain").slideUp("slow", function(){
  setTimeout(function(){ $("#curtain").slideDown("slow"); }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have it call a function when it completes an animation. Have a function called after the slideup, use a timer to wait 100ms, then call the slidedown

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to delay `slideUp` and `slideDown` .. this works for me:

```
    $('#loading').show((1));
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('.toggle_container').slideUp(function () {
        $('#loading').hide();
        });
    }, 500);
```